# tabularx key fails inside a newtcolorbox declared box

Tags: tcolorbox

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{testbox}{
    width=.5\textwidth
}

\begin{document}
% \begin{testbox}                      %compilation fails when this is uncommented
%    \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},width=4cm]
%       test1 \\\hline
%       test2
%   \end{tcolorbox}
% \end{testbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.5\textwidth]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},width=4cm]
        test1 \\\hline
        test2
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

the `testbox` declared via `newtcolorbox` is exactly the same as the tcolorbox with option `width=.5\textwidth` added manually.

However, while if I put another box with option `tabularx` into the the latter it works as expected, if I put the same box into my `testbox` it does not compile anymore.

Any clue on what's happening here?

Comment: no idea what tcolorbox is doing but it's not that surprising that nested constructs fail, there are severe limitations on nesting tabularx in another environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but since the working one is also nested, I was wondering if someone familiar with the internals of the package could explain the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for failure in the first case is that the hack for `tabularx` gets the wrong environment name. This name is stored by the `savedelimiter` option and is set to `testbox` by the outer box automatically. For inner boxes, nearly all options are set back to their default values - `savedelimiter` is one of the very few options which stays at the current value (documented for the `reset` key).

The example is repaired by using the `savedelimiter` directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{testbox}{
    width=.5\textwidth
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{testbox}                      
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},width=4cm,savedelimiter=tcolorbox]
       test1 \\\hline
       test2
   \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{testbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.5\textwidth]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},width=4cm]
        test1 \\\hline
        test2
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

As David Carlisle wrote: Nesting `tabularx` is a little bit tricky. Here, we nest `tabularx` inside a `tcolorbox` inside a `tcolorbox`...